# Program to create spatial grid, average values that fall within grid, write to table

Tags: fortran, astronomy

So I'm trying to come up with a clever way to make this program read a catalog and take anything falling within specific spatial "grid" boxes and average the data in that box together. I'll paste my horrid attempt below and hopefully you'll see what I'm trying to do. I can't get the program to work correctly (it gets stuck in a loop somewhere that I haven't debugged), and before I bang my head against it anymore I want to know if this looks like a logical set of operations for what I'm looking to do, or if there is a better way to accomplish this.

Edit: To clarify, the argument section is for the trimming parameters---"lmin lmax bmin bmax" set the overall frame, and "deg" sets the square-degree increments.

```
program redgrid

implicit none

! Variable declarations and settings:
integer :: ncrt, c, i, j, k, count, n, iarg, D, db, cn
real :: dsun, pma, pmd, epma, epmd, ra, dec, degbin
real :: V, Per, Amp, FeH, EBV, Dm, Fi, FeHav, EBVav
real :: lmin, lmax, bmin, bmax, l, b, deg, lbin, bbin
real :: bbinmax, bbinmin, lbinmax, lbinmin
character(len=60) :: infile, outfile, word, name
parameter(D=20000)
dimension :: EBV(D), FeH(D), lbinmax(D), bbinmax(D)
dimension :: bbinmin(D), lbinmin(D)
103 format(1x,i6,4x,f6.2,4x,f6.2,4x,f7.2,3x,f6.2,4x,f5.2,4x,f5.2,4x,f5.2,4x,f6.4)

3 continue
iarg=iargc()
if(iarg.lt.7) then
 print*, 'Usage: redgrid infile outfile lmin lmax bmin bmax square_deg'
 stop
 endif
 call getarg(1, infile)
 call getarg(2, outfile)
 call getarg(3, word)
 read(word,*) lmin
 call getarg(4, word)
 read(word,*) lmax
 call getarg(5, word)
 read(word,*) bmin
 call getarg(6, word)
 read(word,*) bmax
 call getarg(7, word)
 read(word,*) deg

open(unit=1,file=infile,status='old',err=3)
open(unit=2,file=outfile,status='unknown')

write(2,*)"| l center | b center | [Fe/H] avg | E(B-V) avg | "

 FeHav = 0.0
 EBVav = 0.0
 lbinmin(1) = lmin
 bbinmin(1) = bmin
 degbin = (bmax-bmin)/deg
 db = NINT(degbin)
 do j = 1, db
    bbinmax(j) = bbinmin(j) + deg
    lbinmax(j) = lbinmin(j)*cos(bbinmax(j))
    print*, lbinmin(j), bbinmin(j), db
    cn = 1
           7 continue
           read(1,*,err=7,end=8) ncrt, ra, dec, l, b,&
                V, dsun, FeH(cn), EBV(cn)
           if(b.ge.bbinmin(j).and.b.lt.bbinmax(j)) then
              if(l.ge.lbinmin(j).and.l.lt.lbinmax(j)) then
                 FeHav = FeHav + FeH(cn)
                 EBVav = EBVav + EBV(cn)
                 cn = cn + 1
              end if
           end if
           goto 7
           8 continue
           FeHav = FeHav/cn
           EBVav = EBVav/cn
           write(2,*) lbinmax(j), bbinmax(j), FeHav, EBVav
           bbinmin(j+1) = bbinmin(j) + deg
           lbinmin(j+1) = lbinmin(j) + deg
        end do

close(1)
close(2)

end program redgrid
```

Below is a small section of the table I'm working with. "l" and "b" are the two coordinates I am working with---they are angular, hence the need to make the grid components "b" and "l*cos(b)." For each 0.5 x 0.5 degree section, I need to have averages of E(B-V) and [Fe/H] within that block. When I write the file all I need are four columns: the two coordinates where the box is located, and the two averages for that box.

```
| Ncrt  | ra      | dec     | l       | b       | V      | dkpc   | [Fe/H] | E(B-V) | 
7888    216.53    -43.85     -39.56    15.78    15.68     8.90    -1.19    0.1420
7889    217.49    -43.13     -38.61    16.18    16.15    10.67    -1.15    0.1750
7893    219.16    -43.26     -37.50    15.58    15.38     7.79    -1.40    0.1580
```

Right now, the program gets stuck somewhere in the loop cycle. I've pasted the terminal output that happens when I run it, along with the command line I'm running it with. Please let me know if I can help clarify. This is a pretty complex problem for a Fortran rookie such as myself---perhaps I'm missing some fundamental knowledge that would make it much easier. Anyways, thanks in advance.

```
./redgrid table2.above redtest.trim -40 0 15 30 0.5
 -40.0000000       15.0000000              30   0.00000000       0.00000000    
 -39.5000000       15.5000000              30  -1.18592596      0.353437036
```

^it gets stuck after two lines.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the program does what you want it to do, but you are looking for a few things to tidy the code up.

Well first up, I'd fix up the indentation.

Secondly, I'd not use unit numbers below 10.

```
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: in_unit = 100
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: out_unit = 101
...
OPEN(unit=in_unit, file=infile, status='OLD")
...
READ(in_unit, *) ...
...
CLOSE(in_unit)
```

Thirdly, I'd not use `GOTO`s and labels. You can do that in a loop far easier:

```
INTEGER :: read_status

DO j = 1, db
    ...
    read_loop : DO
        READ(in_unit, *, IOSTAT=read_status) ...
        IF (read_status == -1) THEN    ! EOF
            EXIT read_loop
        ELSEIF (read_status /= 0) THEN
            CYCLE read_loop
        ENDIF
        ...
    END DO read_loop
    ...
END DO
```

There are a few dangers in your code, and even in this one above: It can lead to infinite loops. For example, if the opening of `infile` fails (e.g. the file doesn't exist), it loops back to label 3, but nothing changes, so it will eventually again try to open the same file, and probably have the same error.

Same above: If `READ` repeatedly fails without advancing, and without the error being an `EOF`, then the read loop will not terminate.

You have to think about what you want your program to do when something like this happens, and code it in. (For example: Print an error message and `STOP` if it can't open the file.)

You have a very long `FORMAT` statement. You can leave it like that, though I'd probably try to shorten it a bit:

```
103 FORMAT(I7, 2F10.2, F11.2, 4F9.2, F10.4)
```

This should be the same line, as numbers are usually right-aligned. You can also use strings as a format, so you could also do something like this:

```
CHARACTER(LEN=*), PARAMETER :: data_out_form = &
                '(I7, 2F10.2, F11.2, 4F9.2, F10.4)'

WRITE(*, data_out_form) var1, var2, var3, ...
```

and again, that's one less label.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your reply and I'll definitely try to tidy up a bit with your suggestions. I guess I forgot to actually specify in the main post (edited now) that the program doesn't work yet, and I'm not quite sure if the method I've laid out is actually logical.

Comment: So after some tinkering and implementation of your read_loop, I got it running. Thanks a ton---the read loop is something I didn't know about, and it's super helpful. It wasn't the problem, but it helped me isolate the problem.

The problem was that at the beginning of the file I opened infile, so when it was reading the file in after one iteration of the loop it would have no more lines and freeze up. The reason it printed two lines was because the print command came before the second read attempt.

Comment: Just something to note: The Fortran book I use has both the `end=` and `err=` statements marked with a big "DANGER DO NOT USE". I really think you should use the `IOSTAT` and `IOMSG` parameters.

Comment: btw: the `read_loop` is a name, so it can be anything, but has to be unique within the scope.